# Delete specific Elements in XML file in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

this is my XML file, I want to keep the email and phone number elements, and delete the rest elements (FirstName - Gender) at the runtime.

```
<Users>
  <User idNumber="651635163">
    <email>d@d.d</email>
    <phoneNumber>0528754964</phoneNumber>
    <FirstName>kujygv</FirstName>
    <LastName>uyf</LastName>
    <FatherName>uyfy</FatherName>
    <MotherName>uyf</MotherName>
    <GfatherName>uyf</GfatherName>
    <DateOfBirth>06/04/1999</DateOfBirth>
    <ImagePath>C:\Users\m\Desktop\pictures\me\meirl.jpg</ImagePath>
    <Address>fyu</Address>
    <Gender>זכר</Gender>
  </User>
</Users>
```

so the result should be like this

```
<Users>
      <User idNumber="651635163">
        <email>d@d.d</email>
        <phoneNumber>0528754964</phoneNumber>
      </User>
</Users>
```

I tried using SelectNodes but I was not able to make it work, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check it out.

> c#

```
void Main()
{
    const string fileName = @"e:\temp\Sadi.xml";
    const string USER = "User";

    // list of XML element names to keep
    var listOfElements = new List<string> {"email", "phoneNumber"};

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
    List<XElement> nodes = xdoc.Descendants(USER).ToList();

    // Contains() simulates SQL NOT IN clause
    nodes.Elements()
        .Where(x => !listOfElements.Contains(x.Name.LocalName))
        .Remove();

    // save back to the file
    xdoc.Save(fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to create new xml with only desired elements

```
var document = XDocument.Load("path to the file");

var users = document.Descendants("User")
    .Select(u => new XElement("User", u.Element("email"), u.Element("phoneNumber"))
    .ToArray();

var newDocument = new XDocument(new XElement("Users", users)); 
newDocument.Save("path to the file");
```